# dedicated tunnel between two data center?

Tags: networking, internet, tunneling, datacenter

I sometimes hear the word about dedicated tunnel between two data centers. Say there is dedicated tunnel b/w DC1 and DC2 .

`DC1-> DC1 ISP -------- Internet ------ >DC2 ISP --------> DC2`

My understanding of this tunnel is that there  there is dedicated bandwidth/resources given for communication between  DC1 and DC1 ISP . Similarly
b/w DC2 and DC2 ISP . There can not be any dedicated tunnel on internet. Is n't it ?

Comment: Hard to say when we're talking about "I sometimes hear". It's absolutely possible for large organizations to have their own dedicated networks, though. [Google builds entire undersea cables](https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/04/googles-latest-undersea-cable-project-will-connect-japan-to-australia/), as an example.

Answer (score 2):

This part of networking is typically referred to as data center interconnect.

You have to be very specific in what tunnel means. It could be a VPN tunnel over the Internet. Relatively inexpensive, global reach. Less control over service quality, particularly at peering points where providers don't like each other.

Leasing a link from a provider results in them providing say a 100 Gbit interface that links DC1 and DC2. Probably over their own metro network and not the Internet. Definitely not dedicated cable, they provide services to many customers.

Or you can lease dark fiber and light it up with your own optics. Taking some complexity on yourself. Very high bandwidth is possible.

Comment: `Leasing a link from a provider results in them providing say a 100 Gbit interface that links DC1 and DC2. Probably over their own metro network and not the Internet.` What I understand from this DC1 can provide the guarantee of 100 Gbit b/w DC1 and ISP. Can ISP also guarantee speed of 100 Gbit over internet till to another DC2?

Comment: Internet bandwidth is inexpensive, 100 Gbps of IP transit is not unheard of in a colo facility. But with less control over service, just having a link to ISP 1 does not guarantee ISP 2 is reachable, or has fast enough links at the peering point. Not routing over the Internet isn't dedicated fiber either, but isn't subject to the dynamic nature of the Internet. Either way, read the service agreement for what exactly is "guaranteed".

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, it depends on what exactly what you're "sometimes hearing..."

I think what most people would call a dedicated connection is when you're paying a provider for a guaranteed bandwidth connection between your two data centers.  OTOH, someone could talk about a dedicated tunnel over the Internet, but that wouldn't have a guarantee of bandwidth.

Comment: I think what most people would call a dedicated connection is when you're paying a `provider for a guaranteed bandwidth connection between your two data centers.` You mean provider at both side i.e `DC1-> DC1 ISP` and `DC2-> DC2 ISP` . Right ?